# Can't sum list variables

Tags: python, list

Hi I need to edit my list. Its my list:

```
my_list = [['apple','2'],['banana','3'],['apple','4'],['cherry','4'],['cherry','2']]
```

I need to convert this to that:

```
new_list = [['apple','6'],['cherry','6'],['banana','3']]
```

How can i do that with minimal code. Thanks for answering ..

Comment: i tried many times. created few list for spread'em. I didn't share them because they were useless..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an efficient (O(n)) solution:

```py
my_list = [['apple','2'],['banana','3'],['apple','4'],['cherry','4'],['cherry','2']]
my_dict = {}

for pair in my_list:
  fruit = pair[0]
  value = int(pair[1])
  if not my_dict.has_key(fruit):
    my_dict[fruit] = 0
  my_dict[fruit] += value

new_list = [[fruit, value] for fruit, value in my_dict.items()]
print(new_list)

# output
# [['cherry', 6], ['apple', 6], ['banana', 3]]
```

Comment: Thank you..! Python2[`has_key`] - Python3 [`__contains__`]